# In Perl can I create my data in Excel worksheet instead of a text file. And use the character "|" as a delimiter

Tags: perl, excel, filehandle

In Perl can I create my data in Excel worksheet instead of a text file. And use the character "|" as a delimiter. I am using the following code to create a text file

`for(my $j = 0; $j < $num2; $j++) {
print {$out}  $destination[$j]|$IP_one_1[$j]|$IP_one_2[$j]|$IP_one_3[$j]|$IP_one_4[$j]|$reached[$j]|$IP_two_1[$j]|$IP_two_2[$j]|$IP_two_3[$j]|$IP_two_4[$j]\n";`

In Perl can I create my data in Excel worksheet instead of a text file. And use the character "|" as a delimiter the expression `{$out}` is consists of a filename that i have defined earlier and it reads as `open my $out,'>', "$file.rec" or die $!;`

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

> In Perl can I create my data in Excel worksheet instead of a text file.

Yes, [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) is the de facto standard module for doing this.

> And use the character "|" as a delimiter.

No. You have to use the Excel file format if you want to write an Excel file.

Comment: You can read and write in whatever formats you like until you impose restrictions such as "in Excel worksheet" — if you are writing to an Excel worksheet then you have to write your data using the Excel data format.

Comment: Take into account that the OP is using imprecise language and Excel worksheet a [synecdoche](http://enwp.org/synecdoche) for the concept of delimiter separated tabular files.

Comment: @daxim can i use for loop with the module for example like: 
`for(my $i = 0; $i<12; $i++);`
`$worksheet->write([$i],[$i], 'Hi Excel!'); `
But it is not working this way - any help please

Comment: If you use the three argument form for `write`, then the first two arguments should be numbers, not array refs. Get rid of the `[]`s.